# How do I combine these two SQL statements into one, in a manner compatible with both MSSQL 2000 and 2005?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005, t-sql, sql-server-2000

My end goal is to accomplish something like:

```
CREATE FOREIGN KEY IF NOT EXISTS FOREIGN KEY
```

Since that statement doesn't appear to exist, I'm attempting to sort of kludge it together.

I have a statement that will return the FK name if it exists:

```
SELECT f.name AS ForeignKey
FROM sys.foreign_keys AS f 
WHERE OBJECT_NAME(f.parent_object_id) = 'myTableName'
```

And I have a statement that adds the desired foreign key:

```
ALTER TABLE myTableName
WITH CHECK 
ADD CONSTRAINT [FK_myTableName_otherTable] 
FOREIGN KEY([columnName]) 
REFERENCES otherTable ([otherColumn])
```

I just can't, for the life of me, figure out how to mash them together into a single statement.

It's an absolute requirement that the solution work in both MS SQL 2000 as well as MS SQL 2005.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[sys.foreign_keys](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189807(SQL.90).aspx) was introduced in SQL Server 2005.  You'll have to use [sysobjects](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177596(SQL.90).aspx) to be compatible with both SQL Server 2000 & 2005.

Try this SQL:

```
IF NOT EXISTS (
    SELECT NULL FROM sysobjects 
    WHERE name = 'FK_myTableName_otherTable' 
    AND parent_obj = OBJECT_ID(N'myTableName'))
ALTER TABLE myTableName
WITH CHECK 
ADD CONSTRAINT [FK_myTableName_otherTable] 
FOREIGN KEY([columnName]) 
REFERENCES otherTable ([otherColumn])
```

Answer (score 3):

```
if not exists (SELECT f.name AS ForeignKey
FROM sys.foreign_keys AS f 
WHERE OBJECT_NAME(f.parent_object_id) = 'myTableName'
)
begin
    ALTER TABLE myTableName
    WITH CHECK 
    ADD CONSTRAINT [FK_myTableName_otherTable] 
    FOREIGN KEY([columnName]) 
    REFERENCES otherTable ([otherColumn])
end
```

Comment: Ha, I knew it was going to be something obvious. Thanks!

Comment: Ah, but as @bdukes pointed out, my original SQL won't work in MSSQL 2000. Sorry to take it away from you, but I have to give the accepted answer to him.

Answer (score 0):

```
if not exists (
    SELECT f.name AS ForeignKey
    FROM sys.foreign_keys AS f 
    WHERE OBJECT_NAME(f.parent_object_id) = 'myTableName') 
begin
    ALTER TABLE myTableName
    WITH CHECK 
    ADD CONSTRAINT [FK_myTableName_otherTable] 
    FOREIGN KEY([columnName]) 
    REFERENCES otherTable ([otherColumn])
end
```